# Can I specify a bundle deployment order in RedHat JON Server?

Tags: redhat, jboss

RedHat's Jboss ON Server is a way of managing "bundles" of software and web applications.

Can one specify the order in which bundles must be deployed? We have a set of bundles which bootstrap a machine from standard build to Jboss app server, but the bundles must be deployed in a logical order for these to successfully install.

Can the order be controlled in JON?